# Renovate plugin is not updating all the match strin dependencies

Tags: regex, github, renovate

I am trying renovate plugin in our github repositories to update the dependencies version. For this we tried a regular expression like below in the renovate.json

```
 
      "matchStringsStrategy": "any",
      "matchStrings": [        
        "pipeline-certificate1-(?<currentValue>[^_]+)\\.crt",
        "pipeline-certificate2-(?<currentValue>[^_]+)\\.crt",
        "pipeline-certificate3-(?<currentValue>[^_]+)\\.crt"
      ]
```

and here is my code in the file:

```
'pipeline-certificate1-1.0.0.crt': 'value1',
'pipeline-certificate2-1.0.0.crt': 'value2',
'pipeline-certificate3-1.0.0.crt': 'value3'
```

here only the last matched is getting update but not all the three. Could someone help me here how can I update the regular expression to update the version for all the three lines.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the regular expression using which I was checking the expression and with that I was able to solve the issue,

```
"pipeline-certificate-(?<currentValue>.*)-.*\\.crt"
```

With something similar to above I was able to proceed. Thanks for all the support

Answer (score 0):

The [Custom Manager Support using Regex](https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/manager/regex/) documentation suggests:

> Through the use of the `regexManagers` config, *multiple* "regex managers" can be created for the same repository

So I would suggests defining/using multiple `regexManagers` configuration instead of one with three regexps.

```json
{
  "regexManagers": [
    {
      ...
      "matchStringsStrategy": "any",
      "matchStrings": ["pipeline-certificate1-(?<currentValue>[^_]+)\\.crt"],
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
      "matchStringsStrategy": "any",
      "matchStrings": ["pipeline-certificate2-(?<currentValue>[^_]+)\\.crt"],
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
      "matchStringsStrategy": "any",
      "matchStrings": ["pipeline-certificate3-(?<currentValue>[^_]+)\\.crt"],
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried it but no difference in updating the dependency version.

Comment: @Madhuri OK, it was worth a shot. Don't forget to post your own answer here if you figure it out.